# PRNG Error (Python)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, syntax-error, prng

So I'm trying to make a PRNG:

```python
import math;
import datetime;
print("Please input the seed number.")
seed = input()
systime = datetime.datetime.now().time()
int result = seed + 24252561651525166 - 4551512245 * 1526125162612222525 + tan(pow(seed, 2) + 165815 - 125162161521 + 15612651142516815872195912475199727 - 1123454 * 215 - seed - systime
print(result)
```

But I just get a syntax error at the space before the subtraction of the system time.

Comment: There's two open brackets and only one close bracket.

Comment: OK. Now I a get an error at the number 5 in 215.

Comment: "int result" in python3???

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the close parenthesis for the tan() function. Happy typo-killing.